# Monero wallet doesn't connect to local daemon

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, blockchain, daemon, rpc

I have a Monero daemon running on a **Raspberry Pi** connected to my LAN and it worked fine for sometimes, but lately, I'm unable to connect wallet from another PC to it.

When the issue has happened for the first time, I followed the suggestion to recreate the blockchain (maybe it was corrupted) and everything worked again. The problems happened yet and copying again a new healthy blockchain didn't solve the issue this time.

I use this command on server:

```
./monerod --rpc-bind-ip=192.168.xx.xx --rpc-bind-port=4008 --confirm-external-bind
```

And this one on client:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address 192.168.xx.xx:4008 --wallet-file mywallet
```

The daemon works fine and syncs all the blockchain. If I use `status` command, I get:

```
Height: 1487860/1487860 (100%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 669.86 MH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 1h 19m 48s
```

The wallet starts with this message `´Error: refresh failed: no connection to daemon. Please make sure daemon is running.. Blocks received: 0´` and ever shows this prompt:

```
[wallet 4xxxxx (no daemon)]:
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a firewall, and is it allowing those connections ?

Comment: Try using `--daemon-host` instead of `--daemon-address` with `monero-wallet-cli`.

Comment: @user36303 firewall is active but only for connection outside LAN.

Comment: @scoobybejesus if I use `--daemon-host` with `--daemon-port`, I get the same result as `--daemon-address`.

Comment: Can you reach the server with telnet ? If not, then it's a network problem, not a monero problem.

Comment: @user36303 yes, I´m connecting to the server with ssh without any issues. Ping is also very fast, no problem in this way.

Comment: Please run the wallet with `--log-level 2` and the daemon with `--log-level 1,daemon.rpc:DEBUG` and file a bug with those on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/

Comment: @user36303 also if I solved it? (Look at  the answer below).

Comment: No, that'll just be a normal log, so no need to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the folder `lmdb` from `.bitmonero` directory, then I started again the daemon and synced the blockchain. All works fine now and the **wallet** (monero-wallet-cli) can easily connect to the daemon through the LAN.